# R - create new dataframes by random selection of consisting dataframes

Tags: r, random, dataframe

i'm a R-beginner and i have a little problem. I want to create new dataframes by a random selection of consisting dataframes.

I have 4 (categories), each divided into 10 dataframes and i want to create 10 new dataframes, containing 1 dataframe from each category.

For example, these are my dataframes:

`Cat_1_Data_1  Cat_2_Data_1  Cat_3_Data_1  Cat_4_Data_1
Cat_1_Data_2  Cat_2_Data_2  Cat_3_Data_2  Cat_4_Data_2
Cat_1_Data_3  Cat_2_Data_3  Cat_3_Data_3  Cat_4_Data_3
Cat_1_Data_4  Cat_2_Data_4  Cat_3_Data_4  Cat_4_Data_4
Cat_1_Data_5  Cat_2_Data_5  Cat_3_Data_5  Cat_4_Data_5
Cat_1_Data_6  Cat_2_Data_6  Cat_3_Data_6  Cat_4_Data_6
Cat_1_Data_7  Cat_2_Data_7  Cat_3_Data_7  Cat_4_Data_7
Cat_1_Data_8  Cat_2_Data_8  Cat_3_Data_8  Cat_4_Data_8
Cat_1_Data_9  Cat_2_Data_9  Cat_3_Data_9  Cat_4_Data_9
Cat_1_Data_10  Cat_2_Data_10  Cat_3_Data_10  Cat_4_Data_10`

Creating new dataframes (that's how i do it):

`new_data_1 <- rbind(cat_1_data_1,cat_2_data_1,cat_3_data_1,cat_4_data_1)
...
new_data_10 <- rbind(cat_1_data_10,cat_2_data_10,cat_3_data_10,cat_4_data_10)`

But i want a random pick of the datasets, like:

`new_data_1 <- rbind(cat_1_data_[Random 1-10],cat_2_data_[Random 1-10]... and so on)
...
new_data_10 <- rbind(cat_1_data_[Random 1-10],cat_2_data_[Random 1-10]...and so on)`

Is there any possibility to solve this problem? Actually i don't know how to approach this problem :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one sampling strategy that would work.

Create lists of your `data.frame`s, one per category shuffling them as you go:

```
dflist.cat1 <- sample(list(Cat_1_Data_1, Cat_1_Data_2, ...))
dflist.cat2 <- sample(list(Cat_2_Data_1, Cat_2_Data_2, ...))
...
```

Run `lapply` to `rbind` the corresponding element of each list. This will result in a list of length 10:

```
dflist.new <- lapply(1:10, function(i){
                             rbind(dflist.cat1[[i]], 
                                   dflist.cat2[[i]],
                                   dflist.cat3[[i]],
                                   dflist.cat4[[i]])
                           })
```

You can access your `data.frame`s using `dflist.new[[1]]` for the first one, and so on.

I am sure there is a more elegant way to do this with 2-dimensional list indices, but this works well for a small number of categories.

Comment: Hi, i tested your suggestion and it works, but there are still a few problems. I need 1 dataset of each category in the new dataframe. When i use your example, it is still possible, that one category is missing and when i create the second "newdata" (newdata2) it is possible to get data, which is already in "newdata1". In the end, i want to have 10 new dataframes, each containing data from each category, by random pick without replacement. I hope you understand my explanation. Sorry for my bad English and confusing style of writing :/.

Comment: I had not read your question in detail, I'm sorry. Will update my answer with and appropriate sampling technique.

Comment: @HubertJ.Farnsworth This is a solution, but I am thinking if it would not be more elegant to `rbind` all `data.frame`s in a single one, with two added columns for category and index (1:10) and then subset it from there. The problem with lists is that you can't pass them a vector with the location of the entires you want.

Comment: I tested your new suggestion and so far it works very fine for me :-) Nice work!